# Dealing with Quantifier Order when assuming continuity in $\varepsilon-\delta$ proofs

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

When dealing with proofs, I have the following conceptual problem.

Imagine that, in proving a certain statement, we ***assume*** the continuity of a certain function $f: X \to Y$ at point $x_0$. This means that we are assuming that
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0: \forall y \in X \ \big( \ |x_0 - y| < \delta \implies |f(x_0)- f(y)| < \varepsilon \ \big).$$

Considering this is something we are assuming, we can proceed with *universal instantiation* about $\varepsilon$, and we can pick whatever $\varepsilon > 0$ we want.

**Question:**
Can we proceed with a form of (sort of) reverse engineering, and pick a specific $\varepsilon > 0$ that gives rise to a $\bar{\delta}$ that makes *a fortiori* $d(x_0, y^*) < \delta$ true for a specific $y^*$ we care about, without actually describing it explicitly?

*[In a proof this should read as "Take a $\varepsilon > 0$, such that there is a $\bar{\delta}>0$, such that $d(x_0, y^*) < \bar{\delta}$".]*

I am not completely sure, because the order in which quantifiers are dealed in this way looks a bit peculiar to me.

I am looking forward to any feedback.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If we pick $\epsilon$ that is no guarantee $\delta$ wiil be small: for example, *any* delta will work for a constant function. Now *IF* $\delta$ is an order-preserving function of $\epsilon$ (for instance, suppose we are forced to pick $\delta \leq 2\epsilon$) we can control this somewhat, but if you think about it, "flat" functions (no matter *how* continuous they are) are going to pose a problem.

Comment: @DavidWheeler: If we pick an $\varepsilon$ when can take $\delta_\varepsilon$ as small as we want.

Comment: @Surb: Indeed, but are we allowed to take it (no matter if small or big) such that we know in advance it works for the $y^*$ we care about? The question is phrased in terms of continuity, because there you have a clear occurrence of the situation I am referring to, but the problem for me is more general, and it is really about the order of quantifiers.

Comment: No you can't, otherwise $\varepsilon$ will be dependent of $\delta$ whereas $\varepsilon$ has to be unspecified.

Comment: @Surb: Thanks a lot.